# How sys files were created? from smbios?

Tags: kernel, drivers

We can see the sys file there already some information, where is that information comes from? from DMI?

ex:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu
```

Can you please show me the code in github?

Answer (score 1):

Files in `/sys` are provided by `sysfs`, which is [a “virtual” file system exporting kobjects](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/sysfs.html). See [Everything you never wanted to know about kobjects, ksets, and ktypes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/kobject.html) for an explanation of what kobjects are and how they are provisioned.

The code implementing `sysfs` is in [`fs/sysfs`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/sysfs) in the kernel tree. kobjects are manipulated throughout the kernel source. If you really want a GitHub view, you can look at [the mirror there](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/sysfs).